# Android Http get Session Cookie

Tags: android, http, cookies, http-headers, httpclient

I didn't really want to post here as there is so much information on the net, but I've trawled the depths and can't figure it out.

Ok so I can't get this to work in two scenario's hopefully the answer is the same for both.

My problem is I set the request header but it doesn't seem to send it.

I have a session id s=e32ff223fwefd3 , and I want to store this under "Cookie" , but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the quickest code example I have

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

private static String sessionCookie = "s=12342342352354234";

public static void get(String url) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        if(sessionCookie != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting Cookie: "+sessionCookie);
            request.setHeader("Cookie", sessionCookie);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Null session request get()");
        }
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (int i=0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            Header h = headers[i];
            Log.i(TAG, "Header names: "+h.getName());
            Log.i(TAG, "Header Value: "+h.getValue());
        }
}
```

So when my response comes out the other side it doesn't have my s=232342w3f23f id attached to it!

I think I've explained this right, any help is appreciated

Comment: Ok the code above actually does work, I just didn't retrieve the header correctly to see all the fields. The issue was I had an invalid session Id but the webserver I was using has the WORST error handling mechanisms :-) thanks for listening!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok the code above actually does work, I just didn't retrieve the header correctly to see all the fields. The issue was I had an invalid session Id but the webserver I was using has the WORST error handling mechanisms :-) thanks for listening!

Answer (score 4):

Try `getCookieStore().addCookie()` on your `DefaultHttpClient` object, before sending the request.

Comment: I had to change from org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; to org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient; in order to call getCookieStore() , but even then I can't see how to instantiate a cookie? It's doesn't seem possible, I just want to set a header attribute...

Comment: @Blundell: My point is that your `Cookie` header may be trumped by HttpClient's built-in cookie support. To create a `Cookie`, try ` org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie`. See: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html