# How to retrieve header value in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to send response using headers from Java web application to Android. I'm unable to read header value.

I'm passing header as:

`response.setHeader("response", "ok");`
`response.setHeader("url", androidResponseBean.getUrl());`

I tried using:

`Header[] header = (Header[]) httpResponse.getAllHeaders();`

I'm unable to iterate for retrieving header values.

This is my code which sends request to web application:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[2]);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ssn", params[0]));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob",params[1]));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Comment: you can use regex to retrieve values of fields from the header

Comment: removed `android-asynctask` tag since the question has no relation to this tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541204/android-defaulthttpclient-httpresponse-missing-set-cookie-header-field), it looks like solving the same issue.

Specifically check for `HttpResponseInterceptor` usage.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) is a sample for what you are looking. It looks like you did all good. Your problem is in the receiving side. but to be 100% percent sure just look at the entire message and see if your params appear there.