# App engine java Android get user attribute

Tags: android, google-app-engine, http-get, setcookie

I have an android client that receives JSON data from an app engine servlet. I am also able to get the Authentication cookie. Now, I want to get the User from the request to the servlet.

Servlet Code:

```
   `User user = (User) req.getAttribute("user");
    String cookie = (String) req.getHeader("Cookie");
    if(user == null){
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        user = userService.getCurrentUser();
    }`
```

Android Post:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(Setup.PROD_URL+"/viewselectedclass");
    SharedPreferences prefs = Util.getSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String cookie = prefs.getString(Util.AUTH_COOKIE, null);
    get.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
```

I'm setting the auth cookie in the header of the HttpGet request. I believe this cookie must be used to identify the user on the server. But in the servlet, it says the users object is null.

How do I send a request from Android to App engine to get the current user. I must be missing something here.

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858593/android-http-get-session-cookie

Comment: On Android you are setting the cookie to `null`?

Comment: On Android I'm sending the SACSID cookie to the server. I can fetch that cookie and print it to the console. I cant figure out how to identify the User in the servlet. Though the same servlet does identify the user when accessed through a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this by creating my own datastore entity called MyUser, sent the ID generated by the datastore during registration to the android client and used this ID to identify the user in all further requests. I'm not using the UserService from GAE at all.