# Kohana - API, Loging In, authorisation and accessing session

Tags: android, rest, authentication, kohana

I'm trying to create android application using Kohana API (kohana 3.1) (with module  kohana-restful-api).

And I have problem with making session stay at application (No cookies in apk). I have wrote this controller which I think is a problem:

```
class Controller_Restapi_Login extends Controller_Restapi_Default{


 public function action_create(){



    // Jeżeli przesłano dane z formularza
    $post = $this->request->post();
    if(!empty($post))
    {
        // zapisanie informacji do ciastka, użytkownik będzie zalgowany nawet po wyłączeniu i ponownym włączeniu przeglądarki

        if( Auth::instance()->login($this->request->post('adm_login'), $this->request->post('adm_haslo')) )
        {
            // Logowanie zdarzenia
            $objWiLog = ORM::factory('Orm_WiaLogi');
            $objWiLog->log_akcjaID = 2;
            $objWiLog->save();





            $sessionID = Auth::instance()->get_user()->adm_id;
            $wiadomosc = $sessionID;
            $this->response->body(json_encode($wiadomosc));









        }
        else
        {
            try {
                // Logowanie zdarzenia (nieudane logowanie)
                $objWiLog = ORM::factory('Orm_WiaLogi');
                $objWiLog->log_akcjaID = 4;
                $objWiLog->log_adminID = ORM::factory('Orm_WiaAdministratorzy')->where('adm_login', '=', $this->request->post('adm_login'))->find()->adm_id;
                $objWiLog->log_opis = 'Próba logowania przy użyciu loginu: '.$this->request->post('adm_login');
                $objWiLog->save();


            }
            catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
                //
            }
            catch(Database_Exception $e) {
                // Nieprawidłowy login
            }
            $arrRespons = array(
                            'id'=> 1,
                            'type'=>'e',
                            'message' => 'Nieprawidłowy login lub hasło ',
                            'action'=>'gotoLogin',
            );
            $this->response->body(json_encode($arrRespons));
        }
    } else {
        $this->response->body(json_encode('Błąd Logowania - Brak Loginu'));
    }



 }
```

}

Sorry for bad english, I hope someone understands.

Comment: Its impossible to save session on server without cookie. you can mange sission via cookie or old school session id in each URL

Comment: Can't I store session id in html header friend? IDK really.

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858593/android-http-get-session-cookie